# Python: how to access a class's attribute from a module

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

I have a main file, which contains mainly the GUI(Tkinter code). A window which has `Label`, a `Text` area where text gets updated on users action and a `Button`.

```
# ~/main.py
import Tkinter
import buttonevent
from itertools import cycle

msglist = ['main_msg1\n', 'main_msg2\n', 'main_msg3\n', 'main_msg4\n']


class Root(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.msglist = cycle(msglist)
        self.master = master
        self.frame1 = Tkinter.Frame(master)
        self.frame1.pack()
        Root.status = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.status_info = Tkinter.Label(self.frame1, textvariable=Root.status)
        self.status_info.pack()
        Root.status.set("Set by constructor")

        self.frame2 = Tkinter.Frame(master)
        self.frame2.pack()
        Root.textinfo = Tkinter.Text(self.frame2, width=20, height=10)
        Root.textinfo.insert(Tkinter.END, 'message 1')
        Root.textinfo.config(font='Arial')
        Root.textinfo.pack()
        Root.textinfo.config(bg=master.cget('bg'), relief=Tkinter.SUNKEN)
        Root.textinfo.configure(state='disabled')

        self.frame3 = Tkinter.Frame(master)
        self.frame3.pack()
        self.button = Tkinter.Button(self.frame3, text='Ok', command=self.ok)
        self.button.pack()

    def ok(self):
        text_info(self.msglist.next())
        buttonevent.do_event()
        buttonevent.do_stuff()


def text_info(msg):
    Root.textinfo.configure(state='normal')
    Root.textinfo.insert(Tkinter.END, msg)
    Root.textinfo.see(Tkinter.END)
    Root.textinfo.configure(state='disabled')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    main_window = Root(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The user actions are defined on a different file.

```
# ~/buttonevent.py

from itertools import cycle
import main

do_msg = ['do_msg1\n', 'do_msg2\n', 'do_msg3\n', 'do_msg4\n']
msg = cycle(do_msg)


def do_event():
    # do something
    main.text_info(msg.next())


def do_stuff():
    # do something
    print 'doing stuff'
```

Previously the code was on one single file, Now im trying to write it as a multiple file based on its functionality. Basically, when user does something a message will be displayed onto the `Text` area. Since the `Text` field displays message and has some commonality while every display/activity/update, i created a function for it as `text_info` in the main file.

Say if i want to send a different message on the `Text` field to update from a different file,.. for example from the `buttonevent.py` file how can i achieve it.

when i run it i get error as

```
$ python main.py
do_msg1

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1537, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "main.py", line 38, in ok
    buttonevent.do_event()
  File "/home/buttonevent.py", line 14, in do_event
    main.text_info(xx)
  File "/home/main.py", line 51, in text_info
    Root.textinfo.configure(state='normal')
AttributeError: type object 'Root' has no attribute 'textinfo'
```

1. How can i call a function in the main py-file from a different py-file.
2. what is the best way, Should i make use of a `class` or a `function` for the `text_info` in the `main.py` file
3. If this is not the right way to code, please correct me.

Comment: `textinfo` is a class attribute that isn't set until you've initialized at least one instance of the Root class.. You need to create an instance of the Root class in your original file before you can use the text_info function.  The code in the `__init__` method is never executed unless at least one object is instantiated. Aha. The problem is that you have `if __name__ == '__main__':` which means that everything after that won't get executed when you import main...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by giving a reference of the Root instance as a parameter to your functions:

Instead of assigning to the Root class:

```
Root.status = Tkinter.StringVar()
```

Assign it to the Root instance:

```
self.status = Tkinter.StringVar()
```

There is no reason for assigning it to Root class instead of to the instance self, because its ownership is part of the Root instance as well: it is the components of the Root instance (the Tkinter parts) that fire the event to update.
You could then give self as a parameter to your buttonevent:

```
def ok(self):
    text_info(self.msglist.next())
    buttonevent.do_event(self)
    buttonevent.do_stuff(self)
```

And you can then make text_info part of your class:

```
class Root(object):

    ...

    def text_info(self, msg):
        self.textinfo.configure(state='normal')
        self.textinfo.insert(Tkinter.END, msg)
        self.textinfo.see(Tkinter.END)
```

And change the buttonevent to this:

```
def do_event(root_instance):
    # do something
    root_instance.text_info(msg.next())
```

Answer (score 1):

All "Root." changed as "self."
main.py

```
# ~/main.py
import Tkinter
import buttonevent
from itertools import cycle
curwin=None
msglist = ['main_msg1\n', 'main_msg2\n', 'main_msg3\n', 'main_msg4\n']
class Root(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.msglist = cycle(msglist)
        self.master = master
        self.frame1 = Tkinter.Frame(master)
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.status = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.status_info = Tkinter.Label(self.frame1, textvariable=self.status)
        self.status_info.pack()
        self.status.set("Set by constructor")
        self.curmsg='message 1\n'
        self.frame2 = Tkinter.Frame(master)
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.textinfo = Tkinter.Text(self.frame2, width=20, height=10)
        self.textinfo.insert(Tkinter.END, 'message 1\n')
        self.textinfo.config(font='Arial')
        self.textinfo.pack()
        self.textinfo.config(bg=master.cget('bg'), relief=Tkinter.SUNKEN)
        self.textinfo.configure(state='disabled')

        self.frame3 = Tkinter.Frame(master)
        self.frame3.pack()
        self.button = Tkinter.Button(self.frame3, text='Ok', command=self.ok) # "Ok" function defined for click event
        self.button.pack()

    def ok(self):
        #self.text_info(buttonevent.curmsg)
        self.textinfo.configure(state='normal')
        self.textinfo.insert(Tkinter.END, buttonevent.curmsg) # get message from buttonevent.py and set for window. Fisrst clicking will get initalized curmsg value. if you want get value after click write buttonevent.do_event() above this codes.
        self.textinfo.see(Tkinter.END)
        self.textinfo.configure(state='disabled')
        buttonevent.do_event() # calling buttonevent's do_event function so it means global message will be changed. next click you will see new value for message.
        buttonevent.do_stuff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    curwin=Root(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

buttonevent.py

```
# ~/buttonevent.py

from itertools import cycle
import main

do_msg = ['do_msg1\n', 'do_msg2\n', 'do_msg3\n', 'do_msg4\n']
msg = cycle(do_msg)
curmsg=msg.next() # Add this variable to call main.py to first click event

def do_event():
    # do something
    global curmsg #to edit variable value you must call it as global
    curmsg=msg.next() #Changing variable value for each click
    #Removed text_info function from main.py it is not necessary.
def do_stuff():
    # do something
    print 'doing stuff'
```

Comment: your answer would be much, much better if you explained what you changed. Otherwise we're forced to read your code line by line, comparing each line to the original.

Comment: text_info function is not necessary you can delete this function.

Comment: Your problem is variable transfer. I added "curmsg" variable in buttonevent.py script. and call it in "ok" function of Root class as 'buttonevent.curmsg'. and remove any function call from do_event function in buttonevent.py script becouse you defined click event as "Ok" in initialize Root class. So when click on button "ok" function calls currentmsg from buttonevent script.

Comment: This answer does not behave the same way as the OP's code. `self.msglist` is never cycled.

Comment: ALL CHANGES NOTICED. And getting messages from buttonevent.py